# How to check for paired files in directory of 1000s

Tags: list, file

My first post so bear with me!
I have a directory of >1000 files which consists of paired files. They are genome sequence read files and so the directory looks like this:
genome1_read1.fastq
genome1_read2.fastq
genome2_read1.fastq
genome2_read2.fastq
genome3_read1.fastq
genome3_read2.fastq
etc

These files have all been transferred in from elsewhere and I want to make sure that each file is in a pair and identify which files are missing their pair e.g genome1 only has a file for read1 and not read2.

Is there a command I can put together for this or happy to try in R with a txt file of the file names?

I tried searching for the answer already but wasn't sure how to phrase the question!
Thanks

Comment: Do you know any script language ? What have you try so far ?

Comment: I can do basic bits and pieces in unix (with the help of google) and a bit of bash scripting. Can work ok in R too.

Comment: Well, basically you have to write a script that loops over files `genomeX_read1.fastq` and check if file `genomeX_read2.fastq` exists. On SO, people are here to help you but first you need to show that you tried something. Why not try to write a bash script and edit your question if it's not working ? You'll more likely to have some help that way :)